# Angular/Laravel flow design for multiple view form

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, web

I'm building a web site (no SPA) with Laravel and Angular Js.

So far it works like this: All routing is made by laravel Router (the views are displayed by laravel controllers), but all the CRUD operations are made in asynchronous requests by angular (save, delete, view).

So far I had very simple views: one form to create resources on one column and a list of resources on another column. Like this

[image: CRUD]

The problem is that the last form has a lot of fields and i want to split it in two separate views. I read about angular routing but the way i see it, you must configure the routing for the whole angular module and i want to use it only for this specific controller. What's the best approach on this one?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what are you asking here...

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I edited the post to give a better explanation

Answer (score 0):

So this is how i decided to go after reading a lot, create a new module for my big view and configure the routing only for the new module. I hope this helps someone eventually.